# Integrate datas from standard record type to custom record type in netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suite

I'm completely a beginner in netsuite , So Kindly please don't mind if my question did not show proper efforts in attempting the code.
I create a custom record type using

```
•   Goto customization>Lists,records & fields>record types>new 
•   Enter name as “DemoEmployee” and click save
```

What is the best way to integrate datas from record type "employee" to custom record type "Demo employee" via suitescript. Please help me get started.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "integrate data" between the records? There are several ways to link the records together, but what are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a custom field of 'List' type in your custom record.

And that List type record is an employee list.

That way you can reference the employee record and custom records vice versa. This is also a requirements if you are planning to show the custom record in a tab/section of an employee record.

Comment: What he said:

Here is an example by NS - https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/MarketingSalesForceAutomationPartners/Marketing/CreatingCustomRecordTypeCustomerSurvey.html